Any coproduct in $\mathsf{Set}$ is equal to the union of the images of the inclusions
Let the following be a coproduct diagram in $\mathsf{Set}$:

I want to show that $\iota_A(A)\cup\iota_B(B) = A+ B$. I can show it as follows: The disjoint union $A\amalg B:= A\times \{1\}\cup B\times\{2\}$ along with the canonical inclusions $i_A$, $i_B$ is also a coproduct of $A$ and $B$ so that there exists a (unique) bijection $f\colon A\amalg B\to A + B$ such that $\iota_A = f i_A$ and $\iota_B = f i_B$ so that $\iota_A(A)\cup\iota_B(B) = f(i_A(A)\cup i_B(B)) = f(A\amalg B) = A + B$.
Question: The above proof is not satisfactory since we had to exploit the properties of a particular coproduct of $A$ and $B$ (namely $A\amalg B$). Is there a way to directly prove it from the universal property of $A + B$?

I don't understand your proof. What is $A+B$? What is its difference with $A \amalg B$? Why $f$ is not simply the identity function?

@Taroccoesbrocco $A+B$ is just a symbol, standing for an arbitrary coproduct of $A$ and $B$. It may, for instance, be $A\times{10}\cup B\times{100}$, and thus different from $A\amalg B$. I'd be glad if you can tell me how $f$ should be identity.

This is nothing special about the category of sets, or coproducts for that matter. It is best to prove this in a general setting to (a) get a result which is applicable in more contexts, (b) not having the possibility or the need to fiddle around with elements and set-specific properties.

If $(A_i)_{i \in I}$ is any diagram in a category with a colimit $(\iota_i : A_i \to K)_{i \in I}$, and $u : K' \to K$ is a monomorphism such that every morphism $\iota_i : A_i \to K$ factors through $u$, then $u$ is an isomorphism.

In particular: If you have diagram in a category of algebraic structures (sets*, rings, lattices, ...), then we can define $K'$ as the subalgebra of $K$ generated by all the images of the $\iota_i$, and we deduce $K' = K$. Thus:

Any colimit of algebraic structures is generated by the images of the inclusion morphisms.

In the case of sets, every subset is already a subalgebra, and it follows that $K$ is the union of the images of the $\iota_i$.
To prove the statement, choose morphisms $\iota'_i : A_i \to K'$ with $u \circ \iota'_i = \iota_i$. They are compatible with respect to the morphisms $A_i \to A_j$ (for $i \to j$) since $u$ is a monomorphism and the $\iota_i$ are compatible. The universal property of the colimit yields a morphism $f : K \to K'$ with $f \circ \iota_i = \iota'_i$. I claim $u \circ f = \mathrm{id}_K$. In fact, by the universal property of $K$, it suffices to verify $u \circ f \circ \iota_i = u \circ \iota'_i = \iota_i$. Thus, $u$ is a monomorphism which is a split epimorphism, i.e., an isomorphism. $\checkmark$
*Recall that sets are just algebraic structures with no operations and hence no axioms.
PS: If you are really just interested about the special case ... define $f : A +B \to \iota_A(A) \cup \iota_B(B)$ with the universal property etc.

Another way to express joint surjectivity of the injections without touching elements is to say that they are jointly epimorphic, which also remains true in any category. Interestingly though I would imagine that there are categories in which joint epimorphy of a family of arrows is not equivalent to the "minimal monomorphism" property of the family which Martin describes.

@Olius Yes. I didn't chose this generalization since epimorphisms don't have to be surjective in categories of algebras. So as for the coproduct of rings (or commutative rings), this won't give us what we want. Same for the category of monoids. But even for the category of sets you would need to classify the epimorphisms first (which was implicitly done in the other answer).

It took me a minute to figure out what you meant, but then I remembered that for example the inclusion $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Q$ is an epimorphism of rings. Good answer.

Now only one thing is missing for me: If $K'$ is a subalgebra of $K$ that is also isomorphic to $K$, why must $K' = K$? Exactly what do you meant by "algebraic structures" in this context?

The first quoted statement is a special case of "a monic into an initial object is an iso".

Clearly, $\iota_A(A) \cup \iota_B(B) \subset A + B$ so you have to prove the converse inclusion. Consider the functions $f : A \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ and $g : B \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ where $f$ is constant equal to $0$ and $g$ is constant equal to $1$. By the universal property of the coproduct, there is a unique $h : A + B \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ such that $h \circ \iota_A = f$ and $h \circ \iota_B = g$. The key here is the uniqueness of $h$.
Let $x \in A + B$ and assume that $x \notin \iota_A(A) \cup \iota_B(B)$. Define $\tilde{h}$ to be equal to $h$ except at $x$ i.e. $\tilde{h}(x) = 1 - h(x)$ and $\tilde{h}(y) = h(y)$ if $y \neq x$. Then, for all $a \in A$, $\iota_A(a) \neq x$ by assumption so $\tilde{h}(\iota_A(a)) = h(\iota_A(a)) = f(a)$ proving that $\tilde{h} \circ \iota_A = f$. Similarly, because $x \notin \iota_B(B)$, $\tilde{h} \circ \iota_B = g$.
It contradicts the uniqueness of $h$ hence $x \in \iota_A(A) \cup \iota_B(B)$. Similarly, you could use the existence of $h$ instead of the uniqueness to prove that the union $A + B = \iota_A(A) \cup \iota_B(B)$ is disjoint.

Notice that this proof does use LEM and hence is not valid in a constructive setting. The statement can be proven (much easier, actually) without using that.

More simply, just observe that the characteristic function of $\iota_A(A) \cup \iota_B(B)$, and the constant function with value 1, are two maps $A + B \to { 0, 1 }$ which both have the same compositions with $\iota_A$ and $\iota_B$, so the uniqueness part implies that the characteristic function of $\iota_A(A) \cup \iota_B(B)$ is equal to 1 everywhere, and from there it's easy to conclude what you want.

Let: $$C:=\iota_A(A)\cup\iota_B(B)\subseteq A+B$$
The following proof works if $C$ is not empty and is not a singleton.
We have functions $i_A:A\to C$ and $i_B:B\to C$ that are prescribed by $a\mapsto\iota_A(a)$ and $b\mapsto\iota_B(b)$ respectively.
Then a unique function $h:A+B\to C$ exists with $h\circ\iota_A=i_A$ and $h\circ\iota_B=i_B$.
Now observe that we have $h(z)=z$ for every $z\in C\subseteq A+B$.
Further if $C$ has at least $2$ distinct elements $x,y$ then properness of $C$ as a subset of $A+B$ contradicts that $h$ is unique because for any element $z\in A+B$ that is not in $C$ we can choose between $h(z)=x$ and $h(z)=y$.

The proof can be made to work without your assumption on $C$, see my answer. (Your answer is another proof that we should strive for generality, especially in a category theory context. In a general context, you would not have been able to make this "if $C$ has at least 2 distinct elements" detour.)

@MartinBrandenburg Thank you. Also for the proof you provided.
